# indexOf("\n") returning 0

Tags: java, return, indexof

Let's say I have a string looking like this:

> asdf
>
> qwer

Between those two words is a line wrap ("`\n`"). I would like to extract `qwer` using `indexOf("\n")`, but it returns me 0. My code is here:

```
dataStringTot = (dataStringTot.concat("\n")).concat(dataString); // add line wrap
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(dataStringTot.indexOf("\n"))); // returning 0
```

Where is the Problem?

(I printed out the string on the screen, and there is really a line wrap between those two)

Comment: 0 as result means that the newline is at the first position. (-1 is not found.) Also, there are other ways to express newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dataStringTot.indexOf("\n")` returns zero, then the first character of `dataStringTot` must be a newline character.

In the context of your snippet, this points to `dataStringTot` starting with a newline before you start

Alternatively `dataStringTot` could be `""` before you start.

---

For what it is worth, you could write that more neatly as:

```
dataStringTot = dataStringTot + "\n" + dataString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to write :

```
dataStringTot = (dataString.concat("\n")).concat(dataString);
```

In your original code you are concatenating "\n" to a potentially empty `dataStringTot` (you didn't show where you initialize it), so the line break is the first character of the String.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) is pretty clear :

> Returns:
>
> the index of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.

`0`is returned here so your string must begin with `\n`

Try to `trim()` :

```
dataStringTot = (dataStringTot.concat("\n")).concat(dataString);
Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(dataStringTot.trim().indexOf("\n")));
```